# Bootstrap 3 Media Queries Multiple Files

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries

I wonder if is possible use Bootstrap 3 media queries putting each breakpoint in a different file. I've tried but it seems that doesn't work. Does anybody has any clue?

Comment: Depends on various things. Can you create a demo of it in http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by including media to the links.

So the different styles-X.css will be loaded for different viewport sizes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles-xs.css" media="(max-width: 767px)">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles-sm.css" media="(min-width: 768px)">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles-md.css" media="(min-width: 992px)">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles-lg.css" media="(min-width: 1200px)">
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```